# Feeding C++ code set values during debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am debugging some code in Visual Studio. At the moment I am using:

```
cin << value1 << cin << value2;
// process these values
cout << "New Values Are: " << value3 << value4 << endl;
```

However, to test the algorithm I am using an ever greater number of inputs and wondered if there was a way, either in the tool chain, or in the code, to automate putting these initial values in? What is the standard way to automate this. If possible, I would quite like to avoid setting up a matrix and then reading off it line by line, as I want to keep the test as close to the real scenario as possible, without introducing much extra code - if any.

Comment: Put all the input data in a file and redirect input from `stdin` ?

Comment: pipe the input into your program from a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest instead of automating your input, automate the test. For example, by using Google Test framework (gtest).

Comment: Thanks very much. That looks like a good way to do this. I have tried gtest, but struggled installing it. I have now got Visual Studio's C++ test framework to work. Is there any disadvantage to using the inbuilt VS version?

Comment: I used gtest at work; never tried VS framework. But I am sure it is sufficient for your task (to run your function with different sets of parameters).

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards In case you didn't find it yet, here is a nice tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598953%28v=vs.120%29.aspx